# How to check for a presence of an element in a data frame and if it exists adding values to another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` with letters. Column number of `df` corresponds to a row number of `df2`. "End" column of `df2` includes rows 15:25 of `df`.

I would like to check if there is "D" in a row 16 of `df` of any column. If there is "D" add 1 to `df2$End` of the corresponding row.
For example, there is "D" in [16,2] of `df` then I want to add 1 to [2,3] `df2`.

```
df 
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1   A  V  S  A  S  Y  A  E
2   S  K  E  S  V  E  K  Q
3   R  R  G  E  A  L  Q  A
4   A  K  P  A  T  V  E  L
5   G  R  G  S  Q  P  A  Q
6   E  R  R  K  C  R  N  L
7   A  S  P  K  D  L  P  D
8   E  E  V  K  P  P  T  F
9   E  D  L  V  E  G  L  T
10  R  A  E  D  E  E  E  Y
11  I  F  Y  N  I  S  Y  Q
12  P  I  I  I  W  V  A  K
13  M  T  E  D  V  F  A  L
14  I  I  L  L  L  Q  L  Q
15  S  S  V  T  S  I  V  V
16  P  D  S  I  D  D  D  D
17  S  S  S  E  S  D  D  M
18  -  D  D  S  D  E  D  N
19  -  G  D  S  -  N  S  R
20  -  E  E  S  -  E  P  E
21  -  E  E  D  -  D  S  I
22  -  P  P  E  -  T  D  G
23  -  K  S  E  -  T  E  K
24  -  E  T  E  -  S  P  -
25  -  E  S  D  -  E  K  -

df2
            V1       V2         V3
categ    Start    Middle      End
V1       4.125    1.775      1.125
V2       5.875    1.250      3.875
V3       2.600    1.600      1.375
V4        8.75     1.50       2.25
V5       4.375    1.500      1.000
V6       2.650    1.300      2.875
V7       3.250    1.375      1.000
V8       1.525    2.000      2.625

dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("A", "S", "R", "A", "G", "E", "A", "E", 
"E", "R", "I", "P", "M", "I", "S", "P", "S", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-"), V2 = c("V", "K", "R", "K", "R", "R", "S", 
"E", "D", "A", "F", "I", "T", "I", "S", "D", "S", "D", "G", "E", 
"E", "P", "K", "E", "E"), V3 = c("S", "E", "G", "P", "G", "R", 
"P", "V", "L", "E", "Y", "I", "E", "L", "V", "S", "S", "D", "D", 
"E", "E", "P", "S", "T", "S"), V4 = c("A", "S", "E", "A", "S", 
"K", "K", "K", "V", "D", "N", "I", "D", "L", "T", "I", "E", "S", 
"S", "S", "D", "E", "E", "E", "D"), V5 = c("S", "V", "A", "T", 
"Q", "C", "D", "P", "E", "E", "I", "W", "V", "L", "S", "D", "S", 
"D", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), V6 = c("Y", "E", "L", 
"V", "P", "R", "L", "P", "G", "E", "S", "V", "F", "Q", "I", "D", 
"D", "E", "N", "E", "D", "T", "T", "S", "E"), V7 = c("A", "K", 
"Q", "E", "A", "T", "P", "T", "L", "E", "Y", "V", "I", "L", "V", 
"D", "D", "D", "S", "P", "S", "D", "E", "P", "K"), V8 = c("E", 
"Q", "A", "L", "Q", "L", "D", "F", "T", "Y", "Q", "V", "E", "Q", 
"V", "D", "M", "N", "R", "E", "I", "G", "K", "-", "-")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))

dput(df2)
structure(list(V1 = c("Start", "4.125", "5.875", "2.600", 
"8.75", "4.375", "2.650", "3.250", "1.525"), V2 = c("Middle", 
"1.775", "1.250", "1.600", "1.50", "1.500", "1.300", "1.375", 
"2.000"), V3 = c("End", "1.125", "3.875", "1.375", "2.25", 
"1.000", "2.875", "1.000", "2.625")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("categ", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8"))
```

The desired output would be:

```
 df3
                V1       V2         V3
    categ    Start    Middle      End
    V1       4.125    1.775      1.125
    V2       5.875    1.250      4.875
    V3       2.600    1.600      1.375
    V4        8.75     1.50       2.25
    V5       4.375    1.500      2.000
    V6       2.650    1.300      3.875
    V7       3.250    1.375      2.000
    V8       1.525    2.000      3.625
```

I tried the following:

```
if (df[16,] == "D") {
        df2 + 1
        print(df2)
}
```

I am getting this warning message:

```
Warning message:
In if (df[16, ] == "D") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: I've just added the dputs and expected output to the question.

Comment: To stop the warning try`if (any(df[16, ] == "D"))`. It will check if any of the elements in row 16 is "D".

Comment: How are you changing values? I see only `V3` column getting updated.

Comment: Yes, row 16 of df corresponds to V3 column of df2. If there is D in row 16 of df, I want to add 1 only to V3 column of df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `df2` because of the 1st row all the values turn to characters. Are you trying to do this?

```
df2$V3[-1] <- as.numeric(df2$V3[-1]) + 1 * +(df[16, ] == 'D')
df2

#         V1     V2    V3
#categ Start Middle   End
#V1    4.125  1.775 1.125
#V2    5.875  1.250 4.875
#V3    2.600  1.600 1.375
#V4     8.75   1.50  2.25
#V5    4.375  1.500     2
#V6    2.650  1.300 3.875
#V7    3.250  1.375     2
#V8    1.525  2.000 3.625
```